# What is the Screen Time app in /System/Library/CoreServices/?

Tags: finder, screen-time

I was browsing through my `/System/Library/CoreServices/` directory to try and troubleshoot an issue I thought I had with the JavaLauncher app, when I stumbled across another app in the same directory that caught my eye.

The file path is `/System/Library/CoreServices/Screen\ Time.app`, and this is what it looks like in Finder:

[image]

I was wondering what that app does, and what would happen if I were to delete that app by disabling SIP in recovery mode? Would it have bad effects on the computer / operating system, or would it just delete any functionality of Screen Time on my computer? When launching the app, only a blank screen shows up. I am on macOS Monterey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's that application related to parental control : https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210387

Why suppress this application, just don't use it.